Как остановить прелоадер через svg код?
У меня есть код прелоудера svg, он прекрасно работает, но он не исчезает и работает бесконечно, помогите пожалуйста сделать так, чтобы он исчезал через пару секунд или когда загрузится полностью сайт. Вот код:
<div class="example-overlay">
    <!--Здесь код svg, почему-то не виден на странице-->

</div>


<style>
.example-overlay {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

